# Deprecated: File wp-db.php is deprecated since version 6.1.0! Use wp-includes/class-wpdb.php instead. in

Tags: php, wordpress

After updating wordpres, this error is displayed at the top of the page. I also can't log in as an administrator to wordpres and restore the backup. I don't know what to do

> Deprecated: File wp-db.php is deprecated since version 6.1.0! Use wp-includes/class-wpdb.php instead. in /home/fundacjakrol/ftp/fundacjakrolestwo/wp-includes/functions.php on line 5595
>
> Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/mysite/ftp/mysite/wp-includes/functions.php:5595) in /home/mysite/ftp/mysite/wp-includes/functions.php on line 6865

Tried removing all plugins but that didn't help. So it looks like the problem is wordpress itself.

Comment: Looks like you have enabled `display_errors` in your system? Change that, it does not make sense for a production system. Errors (or warnings, which a deprecation actually is) should go into a log file instead. Then your WebUI is not broken by them.

Comment: You're right, I will do that in the future, but now it is not possible to log into wordpress anyway. I don't know how to fix it asap

Comment: That is a php setting, nothing you can change inside WP's admin section. You need to change the php configuration (and possibly restart the http server to pick up the change).

Comment: Where and how can i fix it?

Comment: I just told you exactly that.

Comment: In my case, I deleted the HyperDB plugin. Also, deleted its drop-in file wp-db.php from the wp-content directory.

Comment: I was also facing the same error. To solve this I just renamed a plugin folder of the "w3tc"  plugin with "w3tc-old" in the wp-content folder and it worked!

Answer (score 0):

Search within template files for wp-db.php replace class-wpdb.php